# TypeErorr: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to make the some dynamic shape weight matrix.

The matrix has 3-dimension, [x, y, z].

So I define some function.

```py
x = tf.reduce_max(some_tensor_x_length)
y = tf.reduce_max(some_tensor_y_length)
z = tf.reduce_max(some_tensor_z_length)

w = self._get_weight(x,y,z)
```

```py
def _get_weight(self, x, y, z):
    W = np.zeros(x, y, z)
    for x in range(W.shape[0]):
        for y in range(W.shape[1]):
            for z in range(W.shape[2]):
                W[x,y,z] = some_eq_output_number
    return W
```

But I got the below error.

```
TypeError: 'Tensor' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I guess the error caused by length tensor is not integer type.

Answer (score 0):

The calls:

```
x = tf.reduce_max(some_tensor_x_length)
y = tf.reduce_max(some_tensor_y_length)
z = tf.reduce_max(some_tensor_z_length)
```

return scalar tensors, and integers. As such, when  you call:

```
W = np.zeros(x, y, z)
```

you're passing tensors as arguments, while numpy expects integers. If you're using TensorFlow v1, you can get the value of a tensor with a session by running:

```
session.run(x)
```

Also, you're using references to x, y and z twice in your code: one for tensors, and the other during the *for loops*. I suggest changing the loops to:

```
for i in range(W.shape[0]):
  for j in range(W.shape[1]):
    for k in range(W.shape[2]):
      W[i,j,k] = some_eq_output_number
```